# Xcode Plist Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist

I am generating some plist files for use in an app I am developing, however all of my generated plist files cause the following build error:

> Command /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copyplist failed with exit code 1

However, if I open the plist with the plist property editor and then re-save the plist file, the error goes away. The plist property editor also displays everything correctly. Does the plist editor add some extra metadata to the file or something that xcode requires? Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like it may be a permissions error.

Comment: When you say you're generating plist files, what format and encoding are you generating them in?

Comment: @Tony The method of generation is kind of sketchy :P. I am actually generating them inside Adobe Fireworks and saving them using a generic file write method that writes the file in plain text. I have also tried writing using UTF8. I have manually inspected the metadata and there isn't anything noticeably different before and after I open the file in the plist editor.

Comment: @Moshe The basic permissions and owner are identical before and after I open the file in the plist editor.

Comment: Actually I just realized that the plist editor changes the xml to use pretty formatting (adding a bunch of whitespace). I am going to try and generate the xml in a pretty format... ugh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might save yourself some time by checking on /usr/bin/plutil used in converting plists from one format to another also has a lint command.

Comment: Dude, thank you a ton. There was a float value inside of an <integer> tag, the plist editor must automagically correct for that.

Answer (score 0):

`copyplist failed with exit code 1` will occur if you've generated (or hand-crafted) an XML .plist file that doesn't satisfy the plist XML schema.  Whitespace shouldn't affect this but misusing the supported tags will.

Using the plist property editor to open and save the file will force the XML into the right format, but long term you'll probably want to isolate the problem and fix your XML generator. (or write an XML-file "fixer" if you don't have control over the XML generated)

Checking you have spare disk space has also been suggested!